# DDL changes in last one month for a user in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, ddl

I want to know ddl(Eg. adding a column in table) changes for specific user after a specific date in oracle? One strategy is by querying 'user_objects' table. Is there any other way to do this?

Can i also find out what ddl(Eg. added column name in table) changes has been done after specific date?

Version - Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2):

Audit DDL statements on or before the specified date.  Capture DDL statements with a DDL trigger.  Use a source control and build management system to track the history of changes.  Or, if you happen to have every archived log since the specified date, laboriously go through them looking for DDL statements (this will not be a fun exercise if the specified date isn't really recent).

Otherwise, no.  You can certainly look at the `last_ddl_time` in `user_objects`.  But there are DDL statements that aren't changes (`GRANT` is a DDL statement for example, PL/SQL objects get recompiled automatically when there is DDL on a dependent object, etc) that will update the `last_ddl_time` without being what most people would consider a change.  Unless you enable auditing, the data dictionary isn't going to be able to tell you what DDL caused the `last_ddl_time` to change so you won't know whether it was something that you consider a change, whether there were multiple changes, or what those changes are.  If you happen to be lucky enough that your new column has an index, you could potentially infer when it was added by looking at the creation date of the associated index.